# How to place UIImage object at the bottom of the UITableViewController's view via the Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uiimage, interface-builder

I have a `UITableViewController` and I want to place `UIImage` at the bottom of this controller's view. How can I do it via the Interface Builder in XCode 6? I am unable to just drag-n-drop the `UIImage` object to the bottom of the view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem and this is what I did:

Change your `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`, so you have to conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Add a root `UIView` and place the `UITableView` and the `UIImageView` inside. You will lose `self.tableView` so if you need it add the `IBOutlet`.
The problem with `UITableViewController` is that the root view is a `UITableView` and you can't add subviews to it.